# QML Column doesn't set child object width automatically

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I'm trying to use Columns and Rows to lay out my user interface.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    height: 200
    width : 300

    Row{
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        Column{
            width: parent.width / 2
            height: parent.height
            Text{
                text: "Hello World!"
            }
            Text{
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                text: "This text is so long that it doesn't fit inside the column on a single line, but I'd assume that column sets child object width."
            }

            Rectangle{
                height: parent.height - y
                width: parent.width
                color: "#aa0000aa"
                Text{
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    text: "Hello2"
                }
            }
        }
        Column{
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width / 2
            Text{
                text: "Hello1"
            }

            Rectangle{
                height: parent.height - y
                color: "#4c00aa00"
                width: parent.width
                Text{
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    text: "Hello2"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Illustration]

As can be seen, the text object width is not bound to it's parent.

For some reason I cannot use the layout qml objects since they lock up my target system.

Do I just need to pepper my code with `width: parent.width` or is there some better way around this?

Comment: "For some reason I cannot use the layout qml objects since they lock up my target system." I would really suggest creating a minimal example for that (like you have for this question) and posting a question about it. :) Positioners have their uses, but layouts are very useful.

Comment: I tried adding an empty layout item to a simple "hello world" qml, even that causes a crash. I have tried, trust me. I have no idea what is wrong with the target system, but it's outside my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, a QML Column doesn't set child object width automatically, and it's the expected behavior for containers (except for a few exceptions like the [`SwipeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html) or the [`TabBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-navigation.html#tabbar)).

So it's your responsibility to arrange children size as you want.

In your case you have to explicitly set the width of the `Text` in order to apply the wrap:

```
Text {
    width: parent.width
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    // ...
}
```

or using anchors:

```
Text {
    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    // ...
}
```